# issue with pushing data into a new array while in a promise chain

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I'm having trouble figuring out why my data is not being push into my new array, "results". newArr[0].mscd.g[i] is a list of several objects.

```
var axios = require('axios');
var moment = require('moment');
var _ = require('lodash');

var getData = function() {
  return getNBASchedule().then(function(payload) {
      return filterByMonth('January', payload);
  }).then(function(result) {
      return result
  });
}
....
```

getData grabs the data from baseURL and returns a list of objects.

```
var getMonthlySchedule = function(data){
  var results = [];
  var newArr = data.slice(0, data.length);
  for (var i = 0; i <= newArr[0].mscd.g.length; i++) {
    if (newArr[0].mscd.g[i].v.tid === 1610612744 || newArr[0].mscd.g[i].h.tid === 1610612744) {
      results.push(newArr[0].mscd.g[i]); <---- //does not seem to work
      // however if I were to console.log(newArr[0].mscd.g[i], 
      // I would see the list of objects)
    }
  }
  return results; <-- //when i console at this point here, it is blank
};

var getSchedule = function () {
  return getData().then(function(pl) {
    return getMonthlySchedule(pl)
  })
};

var monthlyResults = function() {
  return getSchedule().then(function(r) {
    console.log("result", r)
    return r
  });
};

monthlyResults();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't know when `getSchedule()` is done unless you use a `.then()` handler on it.

```
getSchedule().then(function(data) {
    // in here results are valid

});
// here results are not yet valid
```

You are probably trying to look at your higher scoped `results` BEFORE the async operation has finished.  You HAVE to use `.then()` so you know when the operation is done and the data is valid.

Comment: hey @jfriend00, I've implemented your suggestion, but I'm still not getting a result. I am guessing my issue lies somewhere in my getMonthlySchedule function specifically when I iterate over the data given by the previous promise getData();

Answer (score 1):

Your code should simplify as follows :

```
var getData = function() {
    return getNBASchedule().then(function(payload) {
        return filterByMonth('January', payload);
    });
}

var getMonthlySchedule = function(data) {
    return data[0].mscd.g.filter(function(item) {
        return item.v.tid === 1610612744 || item.h.tid === 1610612744;
    });
};

var monthlyResults = function() {
    return getData()
    .then(getMonthlySchedule)
    .then(function(r) {
        console.log('result', r);
        return r;
    });
};

monthlyResults();
```

This may fix the problem. If not, then :

- Check the filter test. Maybe those `.tid` properties are String, not Number?
- Check that `data[0].mscd.g` is the right thing to filter.